# A hyphen in "по-английски"

Tags: правописание, наречия

Do I always need to put a hyphen in "по-английски" or are there some rules telling us when I should and when I should not do so?

Comment: Hyphen is considered to be a part of word, it is orthography, not punctuation.

Comment: Hyphen is not always a part of the word - consider the case when the hyphen is used for syllabification (разбивание на слоги) or as a carry-over sign (знак переноса). Thus, it is a punctuation sign.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. It just didn't seem right to me that something within a word could be considered a punctuation mark. But one cannot argue with a Большая советская энциклопедия =))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"По-английски" is an adverb that is derived from a full-formed adjective "английский" and that ends with "ки".

According to the rules of Russian spelling ([Rosental, D.E.](http://rosental.virtbox.ru/ortho_xiv.html#sect57)), such adverbs are written with a hyphen. You can find the original rule down the link, and here is its translation into English:

> Adverbs with prefix **по-** and endings **-ому**, **-ему**, **-ки**, **-ьи** that are derived from a full-formed adjectives or pronouns are written with a hyphen. For example: *работать по-новому*, *пусть будет по-вашему*, *советовать по-дружески*, *говорить по-французски*, *хитрить по-лисьи*, *по-видимому*, *по-пустому*, *по-прежнему*. Also: *сделаем по-серёжиному* (derived from a possessive adjective *серёжин*, which stems from proper name *Серёжа*).

Also, "по-английски" is always an adverb. It cannot be seen as a combination of a preposition and an adjective, because no adjective can have ending *и* in dative case with which preposition *по* is used. That means that **"по-английски" is always written with a hyphen**.

Answer (score 2):

In the way you spelled the word, meaning "in English language" – always.

You will not put a hyphen in a somewhat similar wording when the meaning would be different. E.g. "по английскому обычаю".

Comment: Well, thanks, but my question is not about "по английскому", but about "по английски". I don't think there can be found a case, in which a hyphen would be needed in "по английскому" or in "по английской". Shortly, my question is about the adverb, not about an adjective.

Comment: Well, thanks, but my question is not about "по английскому", but about "по английски". I don't think there can be found a case, in which a hyphen would be needed in "по английскому" or in "по английской". Shortly, my question is not about an adjective, but the adverb.

Comment: The first line of my answer is a direct answer to your question. Remaining part is just an example of a related case, you can disregard it.